# Get an app icon and display in Jetpack Compose

Tags: jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-ui

Trying to load icons for applications on the phone, I use the following code:

```
val drawable = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(app.packageName)
Icon(
    drawable.toBitmap(config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).asImageBitmap()
    , contentDescription = "Icon", modifier = Modifier
        .padding(8.dp),
    tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
)
```

This gives a round filled circle and no icon for most apps. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out you shouldn’t pass a bitmap to an icon and expect all colors to be preserved.

The icon you receive from an app is a bitmap with possibly many colors, so you will need an Image or drawImage (inside Canvas) to draw it. Changing the above code to the following will fix the issue.

```
val drawable = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(app.packageName)
Image(
    drawable.toBitmap(config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).asImageBitmap()
    , contentDescription = "Image", modifier = Modifier
        .size(100.dp) //Optional, but keeps the image reasonably small
        .padding(8.dp)

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is caused by you setting a tint for the entire Icon with the property `tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary`.

If don't want any tint supply `Color.Unspecified`.